# In the request the oracle to specify to specify a delta in 30 minutes (that the personnel could come to the change)

Tags: sql, oracle, select

my request is oracle, it works fine without questions.

I use it in the API to check the status of the card (access is allowed, not allowed). But there is a problem in the request

I check the card for activity and work schedule. But I still need to take into account the delta of 30 minutes, before the schedule and after the schedule (so that staff can come earlier and leave later). 30. But I had a problem with the schedule from 00:00 to 23:59.

The problem is that the query does (between) for this schedule from 23:30 to 00:29. Only then a passage is possible. I will be grateful for the help.

Annotated selection (this is a selection with a delta 30 min) the last selection is then selected exclusively for the work schedule (but I do not need it in this form)

```
 select a.status
  from EM_STATUS_CARD a
     left join EM_CARD b on  a.ID_CARD = b.ID_CARD and  b.del = 'false'
     left join EM_CARD_ZONE v on  a.ID_CARD = v.ID_CARD
     left join EM_EMPLOYEE m on  a.EMPLOYEE_ID = m.guid
     left join EM__WORK_SCHEDULE p on  m.SCHEDULE_ID = p.guid
     INNER JOIN(
                  select MAX(l.id) id, l.ID_CARD
                  from EM_STATUS_CARD l
                  GROUP BY l.ID_CARD
                  ) t
                  on t.id = a.id   AND t.ID_CARD = a.ID_CARD
  where
        a.ID_CARD = '0000003995E0' 
     -- and TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'HH24:MI' ) between  to_char((to_date(p.FROMS, 'HH24:MI') - (1/24/60) * 30), 'HH24:MI ')   and  to_char((to_date(p.tos, 'HH24:MI') + (1/24/60) * 30) , 'HH24:MI')
     and TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'HH24:MI' ) between  p.FROMS and p.tos
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Having the `b.del = 'false'` condition in the WHERE clause makes that LEFT JOIN to return regular INNER JOIN result. Move the condition to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: @jarlh oracle )but i think the queries should be similar)

Comment: @jarlh I changed the request according to your recommendations

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two different databases,  Are you trying to run on both?  if not, please remove that tag that is not needed.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I might also suggest that you simplify the query -- it seems much more complicated than the question suggests.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, thank you, I will be grateful for your help. I have a table of status, work schedule cards and employees. I'm looking for the latest status of the card (I'm checking to see if this card has been removed) and I'm also looking for the cardholder. I check the employee's work schedule, and if he fits I let him in. Here is the approximate purpose of this query)

Comment: Also `TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'HH24:MI' ) between  p.FROMS and p.tos` needs to moved, if you want true LEFT JOIN result there.